# How to exclude the root for Universal Link on iOS (React Native). It is unstable

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm following this [guide](https://codeburst.io/test-universal-links-locally-ios-e0d7a36332a5) for my React Native app and I'm testing Universal Link for iOS.

Now, I only want the Deep Link to open my app on `/launch.html` and not on root but it seems that all the subpath in my domain opens my app.

Whether:

1. `https:<random-domain>.ngrok-free.app`
2. `https:<random-domain>.ngrok-free.app/test`
3. `https:<random-domain>.ngrok-free.app/launch.html`

I only want it to work on **case 3**.

This is my AASA file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "ABC123.com.test.Test",
        "paths": [
          "/launch/*",
          "NOT *",
        ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "ABC123.com.test.Test",
        "paths": [
          "NOT /",
          "NOT *"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

as you can see, I've tried putting it in the 1st object entry inside `paths` array, and also added 2nd object entry with `"root"`.

I deployed it in my Express Server with NGROK under `https://<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`.

I added this generated domain in my entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:<random-domain>.ngrok-free.app</string>
        <string>applinks:<random-domain>.ngrok-free.app?mode=developers</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is my `server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Explicitly set content type for AASA file
app.get("/.well-known/apple-app-site-association", (req, res) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/apple-app-site-association");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `components` to add a path, something like this:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "ABC123.com.test.Test"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/launch"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

See [applinks.Details.Components](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks/details/components) for details.

Comment: it seems to not working also. i've also added `applinks:<domain-name>?mode=developers` to bypass the CDN cache from here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains#discussion